# Is it a bug of Integrate?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

```
Integrate[1/(1 - x^2), x] // FullSimplify
```

> ArcTanh[x]

But as we see in follow graphcs:

```
Plot[{1/(1 - x^2), ArcTanh[x]}, {x, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> {-3, 3}]
```

[image]

We can see the `Integrate` just calculate the part of -1<x<1. Is it a bug of Integrate? How do I compute the **complete** integration of this function with *Mathematica*? And as I know the right answer is $$\int\frac{1}{1-x^2}dx=\frac{1}{2}\ln{\left|\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right|}+C$$

Comment: Plot just shows the real part. Use ReImPlot of ComplexPlot3D if you want to plot the whole function.

Comment: @DanielHuber As I know $\int\frac{1}{x^2-1}dx=\frac{1}{2}\ln{\left|\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right|}+C$, so I don't need use ReImPlot?

Comment: ? ArcTanh has branch cuts along -Infinity..-1 and 1..Infinity

Comment: @DanielHuber Yes, I know. But could I don't want this cuts result? I want to get that complete primary function. Is it possible?

Comment: Calculate the derivative of 1/2 Log[Abs[x−1x+1]]  You will see that "Abs" has no derivative. It can not be the integral.

Comment: You wrote `Integrate[1/(1 - x^2), x]` which is of opposite sign to $$\int\frac{1}{x^2-1}\,dx $$ which you wrote in that follows.

Comment: @user64494 I'm sorry, I have fixed that typo..

Comment: The derivation of the general formula $$ \int\frac{1}{1-x^2}dx=\frac{1}{2}\ln{\left|\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right|}$$ which holds on each of three intervals of `FunctionDomain,1(1-x^2),x,Reals]` is art for art's sake since an antiderivative can be used only  for calculation of an definite integral $ \int_a^b\frac{1}{1-x^2}dx$, where both integration limits belong to the same interval.  Antiderivatives on each interval can be found by `Integrate[1/(1 - x^2), x, Assumptions -> x <-1 ]` and `Integrate[1/(1 - x^2),  x, Assumptions -> x>-1&&x <1]` and `Integrate[1/(1 - x^2), x,  Assumptions -> x > 1]`.

Comment: @user64494 All three of your answers are the same?

Comment: @yode: Yes, these are the same, but not of the form  `1/2*Log[RealAbs[(x+1)/(x-1)]]`. and not real-valued only.

Comment: As well as `ArcTanh[x]`.

Comment: @user64494 Hello, could receive me in the chat room?

Comment: The proposed result with absolute values is not  a correct antiderivative in the complex plane. The given result is correct, though (of necessity) with branch cuts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I  answer the question  for sportive interest (see the above discussion). The antiderivative of the required form valid on the whole real axis except the points $x=\pm1$ can be obtained as

```
Integrate[1/(1-t^2),{t,0,x},PrincipalValue->True]
```

under assumptions on `x`. Indeed,

```
Integrate[1/(1 - t^2), {t, 0, x}, PrincipalValue -> True, Assumptions -> x < -1]
```

> `-(1/2) Log[(-1 + x)/(1 + x)]`

```
FullSimplify[-(1/2) Log[(-1 + x)/(1 + x)] - 
1/2*Log[RealAbs[(x + 1)/(x - 1)]], Assumptions -> x < -1]
```

> `0`

```
Integrate[1/(1 - t^2), {t, 0, x},Assumptions -> x > -1 && x < 1] // TrigToExp
```

> `-(1/2) Log[1 - x] + 1/2 Log[1 + x]`

```
Integrate[1/(1 - t^2), {t, 0, x}, PrincipalValue -> True, Assumptions -> x > 1]
```

> `1/2 Log[(1 + x)/(-1 + x)]`

I leave the remaining simplifications on your own.

Comment: Thanks....... :)